# how do I compile with mono targetting C# / .net 4

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, compilation, mono

I have an installation of mono 2.10.4 on linux and have been attempting to compile a .NET C# 4  dependent codebase.   I have been able to compile in MonoDevelop, but need to be able to do from the command line / build tool.

executing:

```
gmcs -langversion:4 -target:library -out:foo.dll ... <sources>
```

produces the following error:

```
error CS1617: Invalid -langversion option `4'. It must be `ISO-1', `ISO-2', `3' 
or `Default'
```

The compiler version `gmcs --version`:

`Mono C# compiler version 2.10.4.0`

Further notes:

1. ubuntu 11.04
2. install in /opt/mono-2.10
3. mono install first in path

Comment: by the way, if you look in the build output pane in Monodevelop, you'd have seen the hint: dmcs is being called instead of gmcs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you want to run `dmcs` instead of `gmcs`. From the [CSharp Compiler page](http://www.mono-project.com/CSharp_Compiler):

> Starting with Mono version 2.6 a new compiler dmcs is available as a preview of C# 4.0 (a preview since Mono 2.6 will ship before C# 4.0 is finalized).

(That's a little out of date as I'm now running 2.10.5.0, but never mind.)

EDIT: Alternative, use `mcs` [as specified here](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#New_C.23_Compiler_Backend), as you're running 2.10.

It doesn't support a specific `-langversion` of 4, but then neither does the Microsoft compiler:

> ```
> /langversion:<string>      Specify language version mode: ISO-1, ISO-2, 3,
>                            or Default
> ```

Comment: spot on. dmcs is the 4.0 targeting compiler

Comment: @rapsalands: Most of it, I believe. There's a compatibility checker you can run to find what's missing. You should test your app thoroughly on Mono of course, as there may be some subtle differences.

Comment: Currently one can simply use mcs, as compiler uses System.Reflection no more. Details here: http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.10#New_C.23_Compiler_Backend